# how to use a literal # in a vim string?

Tags: vimscript

I am trying to define a string in vimscript containing a literal `#` which  then gets passed to a shell command using `execute`.

```
function! g:Call_imagemagick_with_hex(hex_color)
    let a:display_command = "! display -size 300x300 xc: '\#" . a:hex_color . "'"
    execute a:display_command
    "echo(a:display_command)
endfunction
```

and I would call this function like

```
:call Call_imagemagick_with_hex('34495e')
```

what I want the shell to see via `execute`' is:

```
display -size 300x300 xc: '#34495e'
```

The problem is that if `#` appears unescaped in the string passed to `execute`, vim  tries to expand it - it seems `#` is like `%` but represents the previous buffer.  e.g. If I use

```
let a:display_command = "! display -size 300x300 xc: '#" . a:hex_color . "'"
```

vim tries to expand `#` and throws an error. If I use

```
let a:display_command = "! display -size 300x300 xc: '\#" . a:hex_color . "'"
```

the shell sees:

```
display -size 300x300 xc: '\#34495e'
```

and the shell command doesn't work. From [learning vimscript the hardway](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html)

> Using single quotes tells Vim that you want the string exactly as-is, with no escape sequences. The one exception is that two single quotes in a row will produce one single quote.

It seems if `'` does protects against meta-character expansion, it's possibly only in certain contexts.
Otherwise, how can I pass a `#` character to an underlying shell command?

Comment: @user9433424 thanks, the `shellescape()` looks interesting. I tried your command and it seems to work from the point of dealing with the `#` thanks

Comment: Did you try `\\#`? See `:help string`.

Comment: @romainl I did think to try that but dimissed the idea because I thought it would only add characters. Im interested to to see what it does though . I will try now...

Comment: @romainl it seems the first "\" is getting consumed by vim. i.e. when I xtrace  what the shell is seeing I get `+ display -size 300x300 'xc:\#59a7da'`. I'm still confused by this issue. it seems like vim's user interface, vimscript seems modal too, i.e. the rules about when metacharacters are escaped depends on the command using the string...

Comment: `:execute "!echo \\\\#"` or `:execute '!echo \\#`.

Comment: @romainl for example you call an user defined function like `MyFunction('#393939')` and vim will expand the `#`. even though `:h string` claims single quotes give you the literal character. but then `system('... #393939')` won't expand the `#`...

Comment: @romainl `:execute '!echo \\#'` and `:execute "!echo \\\\#"` both work, and produce `#` in the shell output. I think that might prove my point. different quoting rules depending on the context the command is run in...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `system` instead of `execute !` :

```
call system("display -size 300x300 xc: '#" . a:hex_color . "'")
```

You can use the return value in a variable if you want, e.g.:

```
let l:files = system('ls')
```

In this case you can prefer using the `systemlist()` that returns a list:

```
let l:files = systemlist('ls')
```

If you need to use special vim char in this context you can always use `expand`.

Reference: `:h system()`

Comment: thanks, I needed to use `call system(...)` else vim threw an error. the `#` doesn't seem to be making it to the display command. also the shell command `display` doesnt have a text output. it launches an x gui program. Still testing now..

Comment: even if I run `call system('display -size 300x300 xc: "#34495e"')` the display command isn't working as expected.

Comment: what is your issue ? can you try with a simpler command (i.e. ls/cat/..) to check if the issue is your command ?

Comment: the `display` command is getting an invalid hex value. I wish I could tell you what that value is, but I cant dump the string as we are passing it directly to `system` . I will try `call system('set -x; display -size 300x300 xc: "#34495e"')` now and see if that dumps string vim is passing to shell...

Comment: xtrace is showing that vim seems to invoking the command perfectly `+ display -size 300x300 xc: '#34495e'` it seems your system idea is working, the problem now must be somewhere else. I think this solves the `#` issue anyway. thanks

Comment: turns out it was a space between `xc: #` causing the problem! so this version of your statement: `call system('display -size 300x300 xc:"#' . a:hex_color . '"')` works fine.